# Apache stops logging when rotating the logs

Tags: apache, logging

I have Ubuntu 10.04.1 running LAMP.  I have logging setup for Apache, along with log rotation.

When Apache starts, it logs everything (access, error, other_vhosts_access, and ssl_access) correctly.  However, when the logs are rotated, it stops logging.

I have no idea where to go from here.  Help!

```
# logrotate.conf (removing comments):
daily
rotate 4
compress
compresscmd /bin/bzip2
compressext .bz2
include /etc/logrotate.d
/var/log/wtmp {
    missingok
    monthly
    create 0664 root utmp
    rotate 1
}
/var/log/btmp {
    missingok
    monthly
    create 0660 root utmp
    rotate 1
}

##logrotate.d/apache2 (removing comments):
/var/log/apache2/*.log {
dateext
create 640 root adm
sharedscripts
daily
compress
compresscmd /bin/bzip2
compressoptions -k
postrotate
    echo "-- `date` --" >> move_log.txt
    mv <path>/access.log-*.bz2 <path>
    mv <path>/ssl_access.log-*.bz2 <path>
endscript
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to restart Apache after moving its log files away. That'll force it to close the filehandles it had on the old log files, and open new handles (and create NEW log files). A simple `service apache reload` should do it (which basically boils down to a `kill -HUP`).

To be on the safe side, you should move the log files, THEN restart apache, THEN compress the old ones. This will prevent Apache from appending to the old log files while you're post-processing them.